# How to set max width / height of image not biggere original size?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

With tailwindcss 3 I need to set max width / height for image and I do it with definition :

```
.img_preview_wrapper {
    @apply  border-2 m-2 border-gray-400 rounded-lg  md:w-11/12 xl:w-8/12;
    height: auto;
}
```

It works ok for big images, bot small images are shown in size in defintion above and image is broken.

How can I fix it  ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**
With class written as :

```
.img_preview_wrapper {
    @apply border-2 m-1 p-1 border-gray-400 rounded-lg md:w-11/12 xl:w-8/12;
}
```

I got a very similar view I need :

[image]

But as I show border around image , how can I remove empty space inside of border at right of the image ?

Comment: Small images are shown like what? Could you explain/show better what is going wrong?

Comment: I mean small images are shown  with very big size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u try to add max-height ?

```css
.img_preview_wrapper {
  @apply border-2 m-2 border-gray-400 rounded-lg md: w-11/12 xl:w-8/12;
}

.img_preview_wrapper img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_preview_wrapper">
  <img src="your_image_url" class="max-w-full max-h-full" alt="Image Preview">
</div>
```